# C# condition within ForEach to say at least one item has been processed

Tags: c#

Time and time again I find myself needing to loop through a list/collection to process each item individually as well as checking to see if at least one item has been processed. For example, if I have a 'Create User' method to see which 'User Roles' need to be added to a user (by way of ticking some check boxes), I would have something that looks like:

```
                foreach (CheckBox in CheckBoxRepeater)

                {
                    if (CheckBox.Checked)
                    {
                        userRoles.Add(SomeUserRole);
                        foundOne = true;
                    }
                }

                if (foundOne)
                {
                    //Do something else
                }
```

My question is: can the foreach and if statements above be combined somehow? or is it best practice to have a bool (in the example above = 'foundOne') to track that an item has been processed?

Thanks!

Comment: It kind of depends on what you want it for. To stop the loop right after it's found a match?

Comment: can the foreach and if statements above be combined somehow? Use LINQ, Where(t=>t.IsChecked).

Comment: You could move the flag check inside the loop, but other than that I don't see anything.

Comment: would LINQ solve this for you?

Comment: `foreach (CheckBox in CheckBoxRepeater)` is pseudo code right?

Comment: I wouldnt want to stop the loop at the first occurrence of checkbox.checked, i would need to find that at least one iteration the checkbox.checked condition was true

Comment: Yeah pseudo code :)

Comment: I feel as if the answers below do a good job of summing up your options, but the best answer is probably a combination of more than one, but its really dependent on your specific scenario.

Comment: Looping is inefficient, especially if you perform the loop every tick, requiring O(N). Go for events, O(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using *Linq*, providing that `userRoles` is a `List<T>`:

```
 // Data to work with - filtered items
 var data = CheckBoxRepeater
   .Where(checkBox => checkBox.Checked);

 // Add all the items into a List<T> - userRoles 
 userRoles.AddRange(data);

 // Do we have any items filtered?
 if (data.Any()) 
 {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Bychenko ! this closely resembles what i'm after, (i.e. process each item AND check that at least one item has been processed.

Comment: @DogBoy With linear complexity

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Any()`

```
bool foundOne = CheckBoxRepeater.Any(x => x.Checked);
if(foundOne)
{
    userRoles.Add(SomeUserRole);
    //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: I like this answer and I up-voted for its simplicity, but based on the question, it also seems like each checkedBox in the list needs to have an operation done for it too. Your answer solves the sub-condition but may not fully answer the condition in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why at all loop through and check for a condition and why not just handling the checkbox `Checked` event which actually would depend on what you are working on ASP.NET, Winform, WPF or anything else and perform your action there.

BTW, your second sub condition `if (foundOne)` is irrelevant since you can perform your logic inside `if (CheckBox.Checked)` itself

Comment: My example isn't the greatest sorry, I was wondering about checking that any condition is met within a foreach loop so that further processing is completed after the foreach loop has completed (so not specific to checkbox events etc)

Comment: Your second point is what has been tripping me up while thinking about this question, I'm trying to think of a case where that sub-condition is valid, maybe an instance where all items in the list need to be iterated first, such as info containing "x of totalFound"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use events.

So every checkbox has a listener to the CheckedChanged event, write a OnCheckedChanged callback and let this callback add an element to the list. foundOne is a getter which returns true when this list has Count > 0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `userRoles` is empty before the foreach loop:

```
    userRoles.AddRange(CheckBoxRepeater.Where(x => x.Checked));

    if (userRoles.Count > 0)
    {
        //Do something else
    }
```